# Window won't draw my Sprite when releasing Mouse Button

Tags: c#, sfml

I am new to SFML and I am just playing around with an example at the moment. I try to draw a sprite where I last clicked my mouse in a window. But some reason the event fires and no sprite is drawn. I can't really figure out why.

I've been looking around in the Documentation but I don't seem to do anything wrong. Help me pretty please? :3

The event is called OnMouseLeftClick and I am trying to draw the mouseLeftClickSprite object. I have removed the bits of code that doesn't matter like the OnMouseMoved event and the OnClose event. They have nothing to do with this.

```
using System;
using SFML.Audio;
using SFML.Graphics;
using SFML.Window;

namespace SFMLExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static Text xMouseCoord;
        static Text yMouseCoord;
        static Text statusMsg;
        static float mouseX, mouseY;
        static Texture mouseLeftClickTexture;
        static Sprite mouseLeftClickSprite;

        static void OnMouseLeftClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mouse.IsButtonPressed(Mouse.Button.Left))
            {
                statusMsg.DisplayedString = "Console: OnMouseLeftClick() Fired";
                RenderWindow window = (RenderWindow)sender;
                mouseLeftClickSprite.Position = new Vector2f(mouseX, mouseY);
                window.Draw(mouseLeftClickSprite);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            mouseX = 0.0f;
            mouseY = 0.0f;
            // Create the main window
            RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Window");
            window.Closed += new EventHandler(OnClose);
            window.MouseMoved += new EventHandler<MouseMoveEventArgs>(OnMouseMoved);
            window.MouseButtonPressed += new EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs>(OnMouseLeftClick);

            // Load a sprite to display
            Texture texture = new Texture("cute_image.jpg");
            Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);

            mouseLeftClickTexture = new Texture("GM106.png");
            mouseLeftClickSprite = new Sprite(mouseLeftClickTexture);

            // Create a graphical string to display
            Font font = new Font("arial.ttf");
            Text text = new Text("Hello SFML.Net", font);

            xMouseCoord = new Text("Mouse X: ", font);
            yMouseCoord = new Text("Mouse Y: ", font);
            statusMsg = new Text("Console: ", font);

            // Play some Music
            //Music music = new Music("nice_music.mp3");
            //music.Play();

            // Start the game loop
            while (window.IsOpen())
            {
                // Process events
                window.DispatchEvents();

                // Clear screen
                window.Clear();

                sprite.Scale = new Vector2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
                sprite.Position = new Vector2f(window.Size.X / 2, window.Size.Y / 2);
                // Draw the sprite
                window.Draw(sprite);

                // Draw the strings
                xMouseCoord.Position = new Vector2f(text.Position.X, text.Position.Y + 30);
                yMouseCoord.Position = new Vector2f(xMouseCoord.Position.X, xMouseCoord.Position.Y + 30);
                statusMsg.Position = new Vector2f(yMouseCoord.Position.X, yMouseCoord.Position.Y + 30);
                window.Draw(text);
                window.Draw(xMouseCoord);
                window.Draw(yMouseCoord);
                window.Draw(statusMsg);

                // Update the window
                window.Display();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Added this bit below for some clarification

```
 static void OnMouseMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RenderWindow window = (RenderWindow)sender;
        Vector2i vector = window.InternalGetMousePosition();
        mouseX = vector.X;
        mouseY = vector.Y;
        xMouseCoord.DisplayedString = "Mouse X: " + mouseX;
        yMouseCoord.DisplayedString = "Mouse Y: " + mouseY;
        statusMsg.DisplayedString = "Console: ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You only draw your sprite *once*. With approximately 60 frames per second, you might see it blink... or not. If you need it to stay permanent, you need to remember the point in your main program and then draw a sprite at that point every time your draw the other things.

You may want to look into game programming patterns. Normally, you have three big blocks that are repeated endlessly: you get user input, you act on user input, you draw the result.

In pseudo code:

```
while(isRunning)
{
    HandleUserInput();

    ChangeWorld():

    Render();
}
```

That way, you can check yourself if what you do is correct. For example, in your scenario you would have drawn something while handling user input. Not good.

Comment: I am not sure how true that is though. About the rendering only for a frame rather than stay. Because if you look at my Mouse Movement code, you can see that I don't draw the Mouse Coordinate text every frame but they are still there. Even if I don't move the mouse it stays.

Comment: From your code, I would guess that you do. Look into your main loop at the end. The .Draw() calls there are executed every frame. Any call not there, will be executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

The events are dispatched and evaluated inside the so-called `window.DispatchEvents()`. When you click on your window, the event will be fired and your sprite will be drawn.

The thing is that you are calling `window.Clear()` after it, so you can not see the result. As nvoigt said, you must render *everything* at each frame, that is to say at each turn of your loop. This is why one uses `Clear()` method from Window, to clear the result of the previous frame.

What you could do is remember the position of the mouse when the event is fired or directly set the position of the sprite according to it. Then draw your sprite along with your text etc. If you don't want it to be displayed before any click of the mouse, just put its coordinates at a point outside the window so it will not be drawn.